# Returning the value of promise inside a promise

Tags: javascript

I have a few promises that need to complete before the function is returned. I have one promise that retrieves a profile. If the profile is of type `artist` I want to the get some json data using the `itunesId` property on that profile, then I want to return from the promise and access both the profile value and the json data. If the profile is of type `fan` then after the profile has been retrieved, it should just return the profile.

I'm trying something like this, but I know it is wrong, I just don't know how to make it work. Currently when I print out `music` it says it's undefined. I know the `getiTunesMusic` function does correctly return an array of objects.

```
var promises = []
var profilePromise = userRef.get().then(doc => {
  if (doc.exists) {
    var profile = doc.data()
    profile.id = doc.id

    if (type === UserType.artist) {
      if (profile.hasOwnProperty("itunesId")) {
        return [profile, getiTunesMusic(profile.itunesId)]
      } else {
        return profile
      }
    } else {
      return profile
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error("Profile doesn't exist")
  }
})


promises.push(profilePromise)

// Later on
Promise.all(promises)
.then(objects => {
  var profile = objects[0]
  var music = objects[1]
  console.log(music) // Undefined
})
```

Comment: I'm not seeing where you're printing out `music`. Where you do that is important. See [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](//stackoverflow.com/q/23667086)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Updated. It's after all promises complete.

Comment: Debug. Put a breakpoint at `var profile = ` and see what `objects` contains.

Comment: looks like `objects[0]` is the actual result of profilePromise. if you are expecting an array there you'd have to do `const [profile, music] = objects[0]` and then try logging `profile` and `music`

Comment: Wait sorry, object[0] contains an array like [profile, Promise]. The promise doesn't seem to have been completed

Comment: It is normal you get that as array, that is how  `Promise.all` works. Change `then(objects =>` to `then(([objects]) =>`. But as your promises array only has one element, why do you even use `Promise.all` and not just `then` on the single promise you have?

Comment: I think the misconception here is that Promise.all  resolves to an array corresponding to the promises you passed. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: @trincot Actually I do have other promises, but I haven't included them in this code because theyre not relevant.

Comment: So then the promised values of those other promises with be in that array you get in the `Promise.all(  ).then` callback, together with the pairs you are expecting. You were just reading the results of the different promises, instead of reading the two values given by the one promise of interest.

Comment: I suppose there is no more question now.

Comment: The problem is I can't access the two values from the promise of interest. I can only access the profile value, but not the music value.

Comment: you're doing it right, ...with `promise.all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `getiTunesMusic(id)` returns a Promise. So the result in this case is an array like this: `[profile, Promise]`.

What you need instead is to chain your inner promise like this:

```
return getiTunesMusic(profile.itunesId).then(music => [profile, music]);
```

Returning a Promise from the callback passed to `next` results in a Promise which resolves only when both promises resolve, and whose result is the result of the inner Promise. In this case, `[profile, music]` which is what you intend.